# LFSR not working on the FPGA only on the simulator

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I'm trying to see a 8 bit LFSR working on Altera DE2, I wrote a code in VHDL and it's working fine on ModelSim, but I can't see it working on the FPGA. Heres the code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity lfsr_8bit is
port (
    CLOCK_50 : in std_logic;
    rst : in std_logic;
    LEDG : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));
end lfsr_8bit;

architecture behaviour of lfsr_8bit is
    signal lfsr_done : std_logic;
    signal rand : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
begin
    ciclo : process (CLOCK_50, rst)
    begin


            if (rst='0') then
                rand      <= "00000001"; -- seed
                lfsr_done <= '0';
            elsif (CLOCK_50'EVENT AND CLOCK_50 = '1') then
                   if rand = "10000000" then
                    lfsr_done <= '1';
                   end if;
                   if lfsr_done = '0' then
                    rand(0) <= rand(6) xor rand(7);
                    rand(7 downto 1) <= rand(6 downto 0);
                   end if; 
            end if;
            LEDG <= rand(7 downto 0);
    end process ciclo;
end behaviour;
```

All I can see on the FPGA is the seed (00000001), nothing more. I think it's because of the clock, it's faster for my eyes, but I don't know how to fix that, since I'm starting to program with VHDL. I tried to change the clock for a button as well, but doesn't work too. Here how I tried:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity lfsr_8bit is
port (

    KEY : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    rst : in std_logic;
    LEDG : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));
end lfsr_8bit;

architecture behaviour of lfsr_8bit is
    signal lfsr_done : std_logic;
    signal rand : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
begin
    ciclo : process (KEY, rand, rst)
    begin

            if (rst='0') then
                rand      <= "00000001"; -- seed
                lfsr_done <= '0';
            elsif (KEY(0) = '0') then
                   if rand = "10000000" then
                    lfsr_done <= '1';
                   end if;
                   if lfsr_done = '0' then
                    rand(0) <= rand(6) xor rand(7);
                    rand(7 downto 1) <= rand(6 downto 0);
                   end if; 
            end if;
            LEDG <= rand(7 downto 0);
    end process ciclo;
end behaviour;
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: By any chance does "doesn't work too" mean you're also seeing the reset value of rand?  The two things these two have in common are the reset.  Is where ever it comes from in the device the right polarity? KEY(0) looks like it should be de-bounced, you won't be able to see sequence accurately otherwise. What a potentially wrong clock or reset connection have in common could also include pin connectivity to the FPGA.

Comment: Are you sure you're seeing "00000001" and not "10000000" from the other end?

Comment: Sorry to take so much time to answer, its because I'm traveling. Well, I think you right, what I'm seeing is "1000000" from the other end. Maybe is a reset problem to, I don't know, I'll look at it again. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

I think it's normal you see the seed on your FPGA because it's the value where the signal "rand" will stop.

On the clock cycle where rand is "10000000", lfsr_done will be set to '1', but rand will also be changed ! On this very clock cycle, lfsr_done is still '0'. Then rand receives the value "00000001" and will never evolve again.

Are you sure that you don't see this behavior on modelsim ?

I suggest, instead of using a button to trigger the process, to use of a very low frequency clock (1 or 2 Hz). You can create it easily with a counter in an other process. You can also use an other seed value which will be different than the end value.

One more thing, the line "LEDG <= rand(7 downto 0);" could have been outside the process while it's only concurrent statements.